# How to position a div statically in my case?

Tags: html, css

I want to position container 2 statically under container 1. The navigation is fixed means it will go out of the flow of page while container 1 is relative it will be positioned on the top as if navigation doesn't exist in the flow. but the main issue is when I added container2 it's positioned on the top I thought it will be positioned under the whole container 1 div (I mean under the img)
any help
thank you

[image: The image that I used]

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

/* I WANT TO POSITION THE NAVIGATION BAR AS FIXED SO THAT WHEN I SCROLL DOWN IT WILL REMAIN IN PLACE */
.navigation{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

/* CONTAINER 1 WILL BE PLACED AT THE TOP OF VIEWPORT CAUSE navigation div is positioned fixed(IT WILL BE REMOVED FROM THE FLOW) */
.container1{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* CONTAINER 1 WILL CONTAIN AN IMG THAT TAKES THE WHOLE SCREEN AS BACKGROUND */
.container1 img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1349px;
    height: 750px;
    z-index: -1;

}

/* SOME CONTENT ON THE IMAGE ELEMENT */
.container1-desc{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 120px;
}
.container1-desc h1{
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <nav class="navigation"></nav>
    <div class="container1">
        <img src="./pizza-3.jpg"/>
        <div class="container1-desc"><h1>THE BEST PIZZA</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>  
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably worth looking into position: sticky; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Second on the sticky

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position` from `.container1 img` and `.container1-desc` elements.

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

/* I WANT TO POSITION THE NAVIGATION BAR AS FIXED SO THAT WHEN I SCROLL DOWN IT WILL REMAIN IN PLACE */
.navigation{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

/* CONTAINER 1 WILL BE PLACED AT THE TOP OF VIEWPORT CAUSE navigation div is positioned fixed(IT WILL BE REMOVED FROM THE FLOW) */
.container1{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
/* CONTAINER 1 WILL CONTAIN AN IMG THAT TAKES THE WHOLE SCREEN AS BACKGROUND */
.container1 img {
    width: 1349px;
    z-index: -1;

}

/* SOME CONTENT ON THE IMAGE ELEMENT */
.container1-desc{
    top: 200px;
    left: 120px;
}
.container1-desc h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <nav class="navigation"></nav>
    <div class="container1">
        <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png"/>
        <div class="container1-desc"><h1>THE BEST PIZZA</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.container2` *is* positioned under `.container1`, but `.container1` doesn't have any content to make space for (since its image has `position: absolute`).
The image just overflows `.container1`, making it look like the div actually has a height, and giving the appearance of `.container2` to be inside `.container1`.

To solve your problem, you could do make the image take up as much background as possible of `.container1`, and give the container a height so you can see it. Also, you should probably use `overflow: hidden` in this case, otherwise the image might overflow the div again.

```css
body{margin:0}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: tomato;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

main > section:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
main > section:nth-of-type(1) img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
main > section:nth-of-type(1) > div {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 300px;
  left: 60px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
main > section:nth-of-type(1) > div h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXdcj.jpg"/>
    <div>
      <h1>The Best Pizza</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Another way would be to use the CSS property `background-image` to give your div a background.